# Recursion in binary tree to traverse the entire tree

Tags: java, binary-tree

I am studying binary trees. I saw online a code to traverse the entire binary tree. Here's the code I got:
'''

```
public void showAll(Node node)
{
    Node parent = node;
    if(parent != null)
    {
        System.out.println(" " + parent.person);
        showAll(parent.leftChild);
        showAll(parent.rightChild);
    }
}
```

'''

What I dont understand is how this function can print the right child? According to code everytime the function is called left child is printed. The code never reaches the right child.

Comment: What do you think showAll(parent.rightChild); does?

Comment: @NotZack - Under what conditions would it be reached?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15306452/traversing-through-all-nodes-of-a-binary-tree-in-java for correct code.

Answer (score 0):

This is a textbook implementation of postorder traversal. Also known by some as "bottom up" traversal.

[image: Postorder traversal]

For each iteration the leftmost node then the rightmost node is printed. If the parent node is ever null then the tree is past the highest node, i.e. the algorithm has finished.

Answer (score -2):

Try to dry run the code with binary tree having, say 5 nodes. And then you'll probably figure it out. Even then if you are facing problems, learn a little about how a compiler calls functions or what actually *stacktrace* is.

Comment: "Try it and figure it out" is not really an answer